# Cargar una imagen obtenida desde api laravel en html

Tags: php, html, laravel

Obtengo una imagen mediante un request con http, lo probé en Postman y las rutas asi como la imagen es cargada y obtenida de forma correcta.
Al intentar hacer esto en el frontend en un proyecto distinto, no comprendo por que no carga la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en la que cargo la imagen es haciendo un llamado con un HttpRequest al download de la ruta y obteniendo dicha imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que el Request funciona correctamente ya que todo el resto de la informacion de la pagina lo obtengo de igual manera y carga correctamente

```
private function send_post($type, $attribute, $name, $value){
    $client = new Client();
    $local_url = $this->url . $type . "/" . $attribute;

    $body[$name] = $value;

    try {
        $request = $client->request('POST', $local_url, [
            'form_params' => [
                $name => $value,
            ]
        ]);
        $response = $request->getBody();
    } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
        return $e->getCode();
    }
    return ($response->getContents(),true);
}



public function download_image($filename) {
    return $this->send_post('download', 'image', 'filename', $filename);
}
```

Comment: Te devuelve algún error? Que ves en la solapa de red de tu explorador? Qué URL te genera? Ves algún 404? Aportanos más información.

Comment: @azeós no arroja ni un error pero no se carga la imagen, opte por cargar desde el public Storage de la api pero el detalle es que cuando se ve la información muestra la url de la api la cual quería mantener escondida.